# File upload failed to ftps server from windows server 2008 r2

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I have a task to upload file to ftps server.
The code that uploads the file to a folder in ftp server is working properly when I used it in my local machine (in windows 8).
Also I am using winscp application for passing credential details to ftps server.

But when I install winscp application in windows server 2008 r2, the vbs code is working fine, but file is not getting uploaded to host machine.

The ftpconnection is like this:

> open ftp://username:password@server:port/

The command I used for connection is given below

```
ObjShell.Run Chr(34) & StrMasterPath & Chr(34) & " /console /script=" & Chr(34) & StrFilePath & "\CheckSFTP.txt" & Chr(34), 0, True
```